# Displaying code with <pre> tags

Tags: php, mysql, html

Currently I'm using

```
<pre><code> code here </code><pre>
```

to display code. I'm pulling this information from a DB for a blog. The problem I'm having is that some of the code isn't showing. For example, in the source code I have this:

```
<pre><code><br />
echo '<ul class="mylist"><li><ul class="left">';
foreach($nameArray as $name) {
    if($countervar == $half) {
        echo '</ul></li>';
        echo'<li><ul class="right">';
    }
    echo '<li>$name</li>';
    ++$i;
}
echo '</ul></li>';    
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

But all that shows up is this:

```
echo '';
foreach($nameArray as $name) {
if($countervar == $half) {
echo '';
echo'';
}
echo '$name';
++$i;
}
echo '
```

An there's some really weird formatting/spacing issues as well. Any ideas as to what is causing this? I should also mention that some of the other sets of code show up just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to HTML escape the code before echoing it using the [`htmlspecialchars` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: The problem with that is I don't need to escape the WHOLE post, just the parts that have code. So how do I escape only parts of the post between <pre> and </pre>?

Comment: @williamg, that is why people write text parsers.

Answer (score 1):

is it escaped? if not, there is [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you have XHTML you can also use `CDATA` sections. They are generally more readable (and pretty!) than a text with HTML encoded entities. Just don't forget to replace occasional `]]>` sequences with `]]>]]&gt;<![CDATA[`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, using htmlspecialchars()/htmlentities() will work however there is a builtin function for doing PHP syntax formatting - checkout [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)() and highlight_file(). And if you want even more flexibility / control have a look at [Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)

C.